# Browsers' Save Image unbearably slow in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, browser, dialog

Starting a few days ago, every time I try to save an image using Firefox or Chrome it takes forever for the dialog to open. According to [this info](https://support.mozilla.org/pt-BR/questions/945397) the problem is related to "jump lists", and by disabling them it should be fixed. Well, while doing that helped a bit, it's still taking several seconds for the dialog to open, regardless of which browser I use, which folder I'm saving to, etc.

I cleared Download history also, but nothing changed (which was expected, since the problem seems to be with the OS and not with the browser). By disabling "show all folders" in "folder options" I was able to cut the time down to a few seconds (before it was actually hanging the program for a while), but it's still painstakingly slow - especially when I'm trying to save several images in a row.

Is there anything else I can do to speed things up? I noticed that browsing files through windows explorer is as fast as I could hope for (even displaying lots of images one after another is blazing fast), the problem happens only in the browsers' save dialog (saving non-images is a bit faster, but I assume it's because there's no thumbnails to show).

Additional info: the only different thing I did the last couple of days was creating a homegroup. There were already other computers in the network, without any lag, only the group is new (i.e. it's the same computers). I don't want to erase the group just to "see if it helps" - but will do if there are good reasons to believe so. (besides, I'd rather have a fix that doesn't cripple my network...)

- Although it *might* be the save dialog trying to get up-to-date info from the homegroup - and finding network lag. Is there a way to select what will show in the save dialog and what will not? Even if it involves messing with the registry? I'd really rather not to shut down the homegroup...

Answer (score 0):

I too was suffering with the same problem. But the I came across this App called "Balllon" on Google Chrome. You simply need to add your Cloud Storage Accounts in Setup. The next time you get an image in your browser, you will get this Ballloon Icon hovering at its top-right corner. One-click and the Image is saved in your Drive Storage.  :)

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-image-link-to-dropbo/kbmligehjhghebleanjcmenomghmcohn

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd rather not save these images in the cloud, but in my own computer. (especially when I'm doing something useful with it - it would be useless to have it in the Drive, wait for it to sync, then go to where the image is and move it to the right place I want it. As annoying as the lag is, it's still faster than that)